# Copying all rows from one table to another without writing out all of the columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to copy over all rows from one table into another that are distinct on one column (Using a Postgresql database). I know that this can be done like so:

```
INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (col1) col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1;
```

The problem I'm having is that `table1` has 100+ columns and so I don't want to write out all of the column names. I tried to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (*)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (col1) *
FROM table1;
```

which resulted in a syntax error. Could someone please provide a code snippet with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns exactly line up, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1) t1.*
    FROM table1 t1
    ORDER BY col1;
```

Very importantly:  When using `DISTINCT ON`, you should always have an `ORDER BY`, where the keys for the `ORDER BY` match the expressions in parentheses.

Leaving out the explicit columns in the `INSERT` is dangerous -- precisely because there might be some slip-up (columns out of order or a different number of columns).  Sometimes when you are writing scripts and you know that the destination table really does match the source table, though, it can be handy.

Comment: Thank you! I created table2 as `CREATE TABLE table2 (LIKE table1);` so I presume I should be fine to leave out the explicit columns, correct?

Comment: @Thetafinity . . . Yes, although I might suggest `create table as` as well.